# Trouble matching alpha and alphanumeric words in string

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following conditions I want to check a string for:

- Contains at least one alpha word
- Contains at least one alphanumeric word
- The alphanumeric word can have **at most** one alpha character in any position, the rest must be numeric (ex. Good: `123`, `N123`, `123N`, `12N3`. Bad: `N123N` , `NN123`)

I have tried the following so far. It's really close, only the first test line (shown below) isn't returning the expected result. I'm not quite sure why this is. I figure I must be overlooking something.

```
public static bool ValidLine(string sLine)
{
    //1+ a-z characters
    string alphaRx = @"(\b[a-z]+\b)";
    //1+ numbers with up to 1 letter somewhere
    string alphaNumRx = @"(\b[a-z]?[0-9]+\b|\b[0-9]+[a-z]?\b|\b[0-9]+[a-z]?[0-9]+\b)";

    Regex matchRegex = new Regex(string.Format(@"{0}.*{1}|{1}.*{0}", alphaRx, alphaNumRx));
    return matchRegex.Match(sLine).Success;
}
```

Here are my test cases (and expected results). Only the first seems to be the problem (which makes me doubt the entire pattern; It's returning false although it should be considered valid.

```
string[] sTests = {
    "123 Fake AB",           //true (NOTE: returning false?)
    "123 ",                  //false (no alpha word)
    "123ff bad xy",          //false (alpha numeric has > 1 alpha char)
    "this is bad too",       //false (no alphanumeric)
    "Good one 123   ",       //true
    "s345f 12d234 alpha",    //true 
    "  good st 13",          //true
    " ave po13",             //false (alpha numeric has > 1 alpha char)
    "    123",               //false (no alpha word)
    "    123d",              //false (no alpha word)
    "    123t test",         //true
    "    12r3 test"          //true
};
```

**Bonus**: Is there a neat way to simplify any of the regex? Or-ing all of the conditions together seems messy.

Comment: Your regexes are case-sensitive and check for lowercase words, thus neither `Fake` nor `AB` can match.

Comment: Oh my god... @SebastianProske I had regex elsewhere in my program doing a case-insensitive remove and totally overlooked it here -_-. I'll make a couple changes and re-run.

Comment: @DangerZone Don't delete the post, get Sebastian to post that as an answer and accept it.

Comment: Aaaaaannnd that was the issue. If you want to throw in a quick answer, I'll accept. I just changed the following line: `Regex matchRegex = new Regex(string.Format(@"{0}.*{1}|{1}.*{0}", alphaRx, alphaNumRx), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);`

Comment: @DangerZone You have way too few test cases for something this comples.

Comment: @xxbbcc I was more worried about the basics scenarios failing than a full suite of coverage at the moment. I still plan on exploring the solution I have before it goes anywhere near a tester.

Comment: @DangerZone No problem, I just mentioned it because you're using regex for this. :)

Comment: See http://ideone.com/l4yXng

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `IgnoreCase` to solve your initial problem.

---

But a suggestion is to check for specific rules via a look aheads and stop on negative look aheads for edge cases such as this

```
^                                  # Anchor to start of string
(?=.*\d)                           # Somewhere in the string there is a digit
(?=.*[A-Za-z]{2,})                 # Somewhere in the string there is are a 2 char word
(?!.*\b[A-Za-z]+\d+[A-Za-z]{2,}\b) # Stop on ADAA
(?!.*\d+[A-Za-z]{2,}\b)            # Stop on DAA
(?!.*[A-Za-z]{2,}\d+\b)            # Stop on AAD for `NN123`
.+                                 # If we reach here, we have a valid match, so capture.
$                                  # Anchor to end
```

Use `IgnorePatternWhiteSpace` since it is commented, or delete comments and concatenate it together. *That is the only option needed for the above pattern.*

This is tested with all your cases above and they behave as expected. But I am guessing you will have edge cases which may require new negative look aheads or adjustments as needed.

Due to this nature of edge cases, **I will not address any new edge cases**, please use my example above as a pattern as a starting point for what will be needed.

Comment: Do the "A" and "D" in your comments stand for "alpha" and "digit"?

Comment: @DangerZone,yes, I needed a shorthand to differentiate the commented sections than saying "upper and lower case alpha..". :-)